# point.change doesn't consider dataGrouping in highstock

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to display percentage changes between points in the tooltips, in highstock, by following the example below:

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/compare/

The problem comes when I use dataGrouping by adding:

```
dataGrouping: {
    approximation: 'high',
    forced: true,
    units: [[
        'month',
        [1]
    ]]
}
```

DataGrouping happens to break the point.change value, which seems not to keep into account grouping and to calculate the change between data entries, instead of just considering the points displayed after the grouping.

Here you can see the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/7bK3Z/ (by looking well, you'll see that percentage changes are wrong)

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Which points exactly? I've just checked a few of them. Remember, that 'compare' is comparing with first point of visible points.

Comment: Hell, I was missing this detail! And is there an option (or a hack) to compare with the *previous* point instead of the initial one?